# How do I label bar plot properly with proportions in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Given the following code below, the labels are adding up to 98% for someone looking at the chart, due to a rounding issue (I think, when converting from numeric to text). How to round the proportions properly to add up to 100% when I label the chart?

```
library(tidyverse)
category <- c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow")
tag <- c("yes", "no", "maybe", "idk")
value <- c(21, 1, 9, 9) 
df <- data.frame(category, tag, value) %>% 
   mutate(prop = value/sum(value)) 

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(tag, prop, fill = category))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(aes(label = prop %>% scales::percent()))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the values vector you need to change a bit and to make it a good touchup. I suggest as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
category <- c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow")
tag <- c("yes", "no", "maybe", "idk")
value <- c(21, 1, 10, 9) 
df <- data.frame(category, tag, value) %>% 
   mutate(prop = value/sum(value)) 

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(tag, prop, fill = category))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(aes(label = prop %>% scales::percent()), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)
```

Yielding:

[image: barplot]

You can count these proportions and they add up to 100.0%.

Comment: If this answer helped you it would be helpful to upvote and accept the answer. :)

Comment: Hi Ranji. Updating the vector dosent really solve my problem. I used a vector just as an example, but the data I'm working is coming in large csv files so I can't just update it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can round off the labels -

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(tag, prop, fill = category))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(prop * 100, 2), '%')), vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]